# What things (or in what cases) can make C++ slower than C ?

Tags: c++, c, exception, polymorphism, virtual

This is an interview question, the interview has been done.

What things can make C++ slower than C ?

The interviewer asked it very deep and always asked "anything else ? " whenever I said something.

My ideas:

C++ features not available in C may have some cost.

For example, if we use assignment to initialize class's members inside a constructor not by the initialization list, the member's default constructor may be called once before the body of the constructor, and then that value wiped out by the assignment.

Virtual functions need to be called by searching virtual function pointer. This is a overhead.

Any better ideas ?

Any help will be appreciated.

thanks !!!

Comment: My answer would be: "don't work there". But it's not really on topic, so I'll keep it as a comment.

Comment: there is no slower than c for virtual functions, c does not have a concept that could be compared. The closest you get are function pointers and they don't support half the stuff of virtual functions without implementing a vtable in c.

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel:  Your comment, "don't work there," intrigues me!  Why not, please?  (Your answer could help me to avoid an unfortunate career-path mistake, so your attention to it is well appreciated.)

Comment: @thb Come to the [Lounge<C++>](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/loungec), it'll be better suited to that kind of discussion.

Comment: Please reopen. I have a large, valid answer to this question, which is answerable in a non-argumentative way, that I can't submit because it was closed while I was writing.

Comment: @R.. It's reopened, please post.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I was just posting as you wrote that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nothing. In fact, C++ is faster than C. Ever compared `std::sort` to `qsort`?

People say that virtual functions cost time to call. They do. But so does the C equivalent of looking up in a vtable. If you write equivalent logic in both languages, the C++ version will be more maintainable, cleaner, and faster.

Edit: Oh yeah, you can call `printf` from C++ if you want, or completely re-do the stream implementation if you want.

And did I mention that the performance of a program which crashes due to a misplaced NULL terminator is fairly immaterial?

Macros and inline functions will "bloat" a C executable just as surely as templates will in C++.

Comment: That has the involvement of template. For IO, C (or lower level function) are faster. I can't say anything about class or struct, since I don't know about them.

Comment: I'm not sure, but calling class method should be generally faster than calling C function with "this" pointer as argument because `thiscall` calling convention uses register for passing `this`. Am i right?

Comment: @nhahtdh for the unlikely case that you are right any overhead would be insignificant compared to the actual I/O operation taking place.

Comment: @arrowdodger Only if the call isn't inlined.

Comment: @josefx: People have tried with iostream and printf/scanf on online judge, and the result is different. printf and scanf are much faster.

Comment: @nhahtdh Of course, `iostream`s use their own buffer. That isn't free. And nobody actually uses `scanf` in real life.

Comment: @nhahtdh: that only proves that some specific implementation of C++ streams is slower than `FILE*`, not that all implementations are slower.

Comment: @Fanael: The online judge uses gcc/g++. I don't know why you bring up `FILE*` here, but the programs are run on the same settings (probably redirection from file).

Comment: @nhahtdh people complaining about iostream performance often use it wrong. Using std::endl instead of "\n" and keeping the streams synchronized with cstdio are some of the most common mistakes.

Comment: @nhahtdh: I bring up `FILE*` because *you* started comparing C++ streams to C I/O.

Comment: @josefx: Well, I probably will try later to see if there is any difference.

Comment: @Fanael: Can you enlighten me how it has anything to do with the comparison?

Comment: @josefx: as a user of C++, how do you keep it from syncing with cstdio? (nevermind, lol, it was just a flag on iostream. you learn something new every day.) :)

Comment: C++ is *not* inherently faster than C: C++ compile-time generics via templates are not necessarily faster than C runtime-generics via function pointers as a good optimizer can level the playing field by function cloning (ie creating a specialised version with the virtual calls inlined); of course, that's only possible if the function is available in the translation unit: see http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3717463 for how to get C++-comparable performance from `qsort()` and https://bitbucket.org/cggaertner/listsort for a custom sorting algorithm in C which beats `std::forward_list::sort()`

Comment: This answer is simply wrong. Anything that can be done with templates can be done with inline functions and possibly macros in C. But more to the point, OP asked *which C++ features tend to make C++ slower*, which is a very good question if you want to write C++ but don't want your code to be stereotypically slow and bloated.

Comment: @R..: Yeah, because C macros are completely safe to use. Oh, wait... And like all stereotypes, "slow and bloated" is, at best, out of date for C++ code.

Comment: I came here to give serious answers not to engage in petty language wars. I don't doubt, with a sufficiently advanced toolchain and a smart person writing the code, that you can produce fast, non-bloated programs with C++. But it's clear that a large number (I would say the vast majority) of C++ programs are very slow and bloated. A great example is all the work that went into alternate malloc implementations to make up for how slow KDE was (mostly due to the first issue I explained in my answer).

Comment: @R..: Most likely because the people coding it were morons. You need something a little more than just "X piece of software was bad". That's just as fallacious as "Linux kernel is in C".

Comment: Again, this is in no way a judgement about the language. But it's a fact that there's a lot of really bad (at least in the way of slow/bloated) software written in C++, largely due to the (in your words) "morons" writing the software. Answers to OP's question should focus on how to avoid being one of those "morons".

Comment: @R..: There's plenty of morons writing bad software in every language, and there's nothing specific about C++ here.

Comment: @R.. Care to enlighten us as to say which programming tools (esp. languages) tend to produce *non-bloated* software (whatever that means anyway.) Most computing intensive end-user software (like web browsers, language runtimes and games...) are done in C++ but hey, I guess the devs *are simply stupid*

Comment: @eq-: No, because as I already mentioned, the point here is how to avoid the pitfalls in C++, not to have an argument over which languages suck/rock/whatever.

Comment: @R..: The question implies that certain *language features* are fundamentally slow when compared to the C equivalent, not that certain *implementations* or *mis-uses* of them are slow.

Comment: It could be read that way, in which case it's rather argumentative. But I think it would make more sense (from a logical standpoint and a getting-the-job standpoint) to explain which language features have the *potential* to make your program slow.

Comment: @R..: I personally find the question quite unambiguously that. However, if you were to read it the other way, you would still have to accept that comparing safe and unsafe interfaces isn't really a valid comparison.

Comment: Your argument about "safe" and "unsafe" is off-topic and a distraction from the question. The interview question was not about the relative safety of languages (which is usually overhyped; see all the vulns in JS, PHP, etc. code even though they were supposed to be "safe" languages without pointers). It was about speed.

Comment: @R..: Nobody cares how fast a program is if it crashes. Performance is only ever relevant to anybody once you have safety. It's like having money. It's kinda silly to have a bunch of money if you're missing major internal organs. Not to mention the fact that you can roll a perfectly safe `std::string` style interface which can match the speed offered by `snprintf` and friends, an unsafe interface.

Answer (score 28):

There's nothing *inherently* slower about C++ versus C, but still, idiomatic C++ code tends to be a lot slower and heavier than idiomatic C code doing the same task. The word idiomatic is key here; if you write your C code to perform a task exactly the same way you would perform that task in C++, it's going to be just as slow. On the other hand, if you're aware of where the hidden costs typically creep up in C++, you can make an effort to keep them minimal and get the benefits of C++ without as many of the costs.

First and foremost is dynamic memory allocation. In C, you see every bit of dynamic memory allocation you do, because it's all explicit (either in the form of calls to `malloc` or calls to third-party library functions which return allocated objects). In C++, many class objects where the object's storage duration is automatic will still incur dynamic memory allocation due to hidden allocations taking place in their constructors. A good C++ STL (or third-party library) implementation can avoid a lot of this cost by including small buffers inside the objects themselves, and only performing dynamic allocations when a large buffer is needed, but very few do this in practice. (If I'm not mistaken, llvm's libc++ does, but GCC's libstdc++ does not.) Since this is a quality of implementation issue that's often outside the control of your own code, the main thing you can do here to minimize the impact is be aware of the possibility that automatic objects allocate dynamic memory, and avoid creating more than you need (for example, by using pointers or references when possible). This has other benefits to your code, too.

Another big area is string handling. In idiomatic C, strings are constructed in one fell swoop with `snprintf` or similar. In C++ and many other languages with more powerful string classes/types, concatenation (piece by piece construction) of strings is idiomatic. This is very inefficient, leading to multiple allocation/deallocation steps, copies, etc. not to mention the resulting memory fragmentation. I'm not sure what best practices for C++ would involve (I'm not well-versed in C++), but there should be ways to minimize this impact.

And most generally, of course, hidden code. This is sort of a catch-all. It's easy in C++ to write code whereby a lot of extra code you never see gets executed. Constructors/destructors, overloaded operators, and templates are the most obvious causes. Again, if you want to do things *the same way* in C, the cost will be the same, but the difference is that in C, you *see* the cost right away because you have to write it yourself.

Comment: A lot of your answer has nothing to do with C++ and everything to do with the fact that the Standard is general-purpose, not specific. For example, you can write an expression template based string class which can perform exactly equivalently to hand-rolled C with exactly one allocation step, if necessary. If you actually have a performance problem with a Standard component, just roll one that meets your more specific needs. It's not some wonder-library, it's just to get started and cover most uses. `snprintf` and friends are so hideously unsafe that they're not really a fair comparison.

Comment: I agree totally that you can do that; my point is that if you want to avoid the pitfalls that make things costly in C++, you might have to do that. As for your remarks about `snprintf`, this is about the third time you've thrown around accusations of something being "unsafe" with no justification, and it's off-topic and bordering on trolling.

Comment: All you have to do is *look at the interface*. Pass `sizeof(src)` instead of `sizeof(dest)` and you're guaranteed to get a nasty problem- not to mention the fact that you're violating DRY by writing it a billion times over. Or writing a format specifier and then not updating it when you change the type of a variable. Or having too many format specifiers. Or accidentally manually overwriting the NULL terminator. All of these errors are permitted by the interface and happen in real C programs. However, it is *impossible* to make an equivalent mistake by using the C++ Standard string handling.

Comment: You're free not to like C, but in your particular example, static analysis catches that with no problem. In general, however, `snprintf` is a much more powerful interface than the tools you prefer, because it allows you to do all kinds of work (e.g. treating sub-ranges of a buffer as destination buffers in themselves) that would not be possible if base pointer and size were not separate arguments. If you want a more limited interface, however, it's possible to construct one on top of `snprintf` or write your own. Though I would just set policies if your coders are likely to mess it up.

Comment: I'm not at all saying that it's impossible to use safely. All I am saying is that you're comparing one thing with guaranteed safety, and another thing where it's not just possible, but common, for it to be used unsafely, which in my opinion, is a bit of a bad comparison. Not to mention that *some* people need very-high-performance strings, but *everybody* needs safe string handling.

Comment: I can't even remember the last time I saw `snprintf` used unsafely. As long as it's used idiomatically, you either have `buf, sizeof buf` as the first 2 arguments (immediately obvious that it's correct as long as you can see that `buf` is an array and not a pointer) or you have a pointer/size pair that are being passed around together, and where it's obvious that as long as the caller didn't break the interface contract, your function is fine. There's **plenty** of bad use of `strcat` and other legacy hell like that in C, but usually folks who know to use `snprintf` know what they're doing...

Comment: There's still a significant difference between "usually", and "guaranteed". Not to mention the idea that if you call `snprintf` a thousand times or ten thousand times, no matter how experienced you are, you'll make a mistake, because that's why DRY exists, and no static analysis can protect you from such things. Unless, of course, you were to leverage the type system... but that's starting to sound an awful lot like `std::string`.

Comment: By the way, almost every real-world use of `std::string` is unsafe because the exception on allocation failure is not gracefully handled. You might call that "just DoS", but if files are left in inconsistent state, it could lead to further compromise as well. I agree you can make it safe (either making your application robust against asynchronous termination while writing files, or properly handling exceptions), but if you do it ten thousand times, no matter how experienced you are, you'll make a mistake. See how silly this argument is starting to sound?

Comment: Nope. You only ever have to write one cleanup in your destructor, and then it's not going to matter why it was called. You don't have to write it every place you use it (unlike being safe with snprintf). More relevantly, a whole bunch of OS routines and other things probably won't work if you run out of virtual memory, so it would be kinda hard to ever perform any useful work in that case no matter what user-mode code you write. Exception safety isn't a thing you write into every single function, it's a thing you design in once and then it's done.

Answer (score 7):

Wow ... a lot of love for C++ in the answers, so I'll rant a bit as Devil's Advocate.

At the atomic language scale, I'd agree that little or nothing is intrinsically significantly "slower" executing in C++. At the higher level, it get's complicated. C++ is a useful tool, but is often a [panache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panache) bandied about inappropriately as an solution for a all problems. It's better when we use the simplest language to describe a problem, and sometimes that's C++ other times ... assembly, opcodes, interpreted languages.

C++ relies to a larger degree on the compiler to "interpret" intention, crawling through many layers of templates, classes, macros, etc..., with multiple iterations. Each loop through the translation has the potential of encountering the [law of unintended consequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unintended_consequences) . As far as I know, processors don't have registers or opcodes that natively handle the constructs C++ has, so each has to be broken down to a simplified portion. In this area, the compiler and code standards are king. In some cases it's the philosophical equivalent of a teacher with PHD in Mathematics (the compiler) teaching third graders (the processor).

I like C++ and use it conservatively but I've seen little of it written well over the years. I'd like to force some to look at the assembly or machine code ultimately regurgitated by the build, until they understood how convoluted it can be. Bad C is one thing, bad C++ can be exponentially worse.

The better answer for the interview... "When would your team view C++ as not the answer to the problem?"

Answer (score 6):

Most features in C++ are a solution to solve a (potential) problem in C (for example: constructors to ensure validity of created data bundles (`struct` in C)

This means that to write a correct program in C that tries to avoid a problem for which there is a C++ feature, you will have to perform similar actions that C++ is doing behind the scenes.  This results in similar performances in both cases.

Of course you can always write sloppy programs that are "faster", but will not work correctly in all cases

Comment: Or worse performance for C, since it's unlikely you'll be able to optimize the C version well enough.

Comment: Or faster performance, because your code simply doesn't require the solutions that the std was designed to solve.

Answer (score 5):

> Any better ideas ?  Any help will be appreciated.

The STL as such in C++ is seldom slower than a specially coded equivalent in C.  However, the *convenience* of the STL can occasionally lead one to write slower code.  For example, suppose a fixed set of 100 items out of which a variable selection of 10 or 15 is made.  Suppose that a program's time-critical loop asks many times whether item `i` has been selected.  A fast data structure to support such a time-critical loop would be an array (or vector or the like) of 100 bools.  However, to populate a `std::set<size_t>` might be easier to code in C++ than to populate the array.  The C++ programmer might prefer the set over the array for this reason.

Of course, whether the slower code is a problem depends on how much service the time-critical loop will see.  If it takes an extra half hour to program the array technique, and the total execution-time savings over the life of the program is 0.5 seconds, the set technique is probably preferable.  On the other hand, if the total execution-time savings is 30 days, then the array technique may be preferable.

Many similar answers along these lines might be given.  Good luck with your interview.

Comment: You can't have a `std::set<bool>` with 100 entries. There are only 2 values for `bool`, `true` and `false`, so at most it can only contain 2 values.

Comment: It should be edited to `vector`, but `bitset` (STL) is a faster solution (probably better than char array) for the example problem.

Comment: @DeadMG Maybe he meant multiset ;-)

Comment: @DeadMG:  You're right, or course.  Thanks.  I meant `std::set<size_t>`.  Editing the answer now.

Answer (score 4):

C has `restrict`, C++ doesn't, although most compilers have it as an extension.

There's also variable length arrays which C++ doesn't have.

Comment: A heap based memory arena can allocate faster than `alloca`.

Comment: @DeadMG: Depends on the implementation. On one with a frame pointer, `alloca(n)` is purely `__asm__ __volatile__ ( "sub %1,%%esp ; mov %%esp, %0" : "=r"(result) : "g"(n));` or equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

A priori not a performance issue, but the LLVM codebase uses neither RTTI nor exceptions because they are considered [too costly in terms of code size](http://llvm.org/docs/CodingStandards.html#ci_rtti_exceptions).

Comment: Note that in C++ code that makes proper use of C++ (e.g. using STL and most nontrivial classes), it's impossible to write a correct program without exceptions. This is because allocations that take place in constructors can fail, and usually the only way to report and handle a failure without crash-and-burn is via exceptions.

Comment: Its false. You can allocate using nothrow new, or even with malloc, you don't need exception too write correct code.