# Is there a great deal of extra overhead when using C++ over C?

Tags: c++, c, microcontroller

I have been programming microcontrollers for a bit using C, but like the intuition that C++ brings to the table with its object-oriented nature.

What are the major drawbacks of using C++ in general? Aside from class instantiation and deletion, where the associated constructors and destructors are called, is there a significant amount of overhead compared to an equivalent implementation using C?

Specifically, I am concerned about the following areas:

- extra memory usage (RAM)
- extra instructions required (and consequentially CPU time)
- extra memory required to store the C++ program (i.e. result of compilation)

Comment: Possibly useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775087/what-things-or-in-what-cases-can-make-c-slower-than-c

Comment: C++ lives by the principle of "you only pay for what you use". There are some expensive features, but if you don't use them you won't suffer for them. Plus those are things you can't do in C anyway. Note that the strong typing features can make C++ *faster* than C because it gives the compiler more information to optimize with. Compare C's `qsort` with `std::sort`.

Comment: @Brian: I was just about to post that. Here's a link to my answer on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10775087/what-things-or-in-what-cases-can-make-c-slower-than-c/10776252#10776252

Comment: @Adam: The classic `qsort` vs `std::sort` thing is a fallacy. There's no fundamental reason `qsort` can't be just as optimized, and in fact it will be with any decent compiler if there's an inline implementation in `stdlib.h`. Of course you pay an extreme cost for such inlining (and for `std::sort`) that's probably highly undesirable on embedded microcontrollers.

Comment: My usual answer is you have to measure it. All answers here give you general advices, but if you are really concerned about performance, you have to benchmark. And not any artificial test, but use cases you have in mind. A second dimension is the benefit of C++. What are the development costs compared to buying more memory, have maybe less bugs or earlier releases?

Answer (score 3):

Programming in C++ won't inherently give you a slower/bigger/< insert worst nightmare here> program.  However, that are some reasons to prefer C to C++ for microcontrollers:

- Writing a C++ compiler is much harder than writing a C compiler.  Thus it can be impossible to find a C++ compiler for a small processor, but a C compiler can always be found.  This may or may not bother you.  Even if it doesn't bother you now, it might in the future if you want to port your code.
- C++ can do things behind your back.  Vectors are much easier to deal with than arrays because a lot of the work is done for you.  But this means that the library is allocating memory for you and it does it when *it* wants to.  If memory is at a premium then you might want to have full control.  Also, if there is an element of real time in your use case then you probably want to allocate all memory up front, so that each call is predictable (an insert to a vector might take a long time if you hit the bounds where it needs to grow ... this might mean copying the vector to a new location on the heap).
- C++ has features that take up more memory that are very easy to use.  If you make functions virtual then the compiler might need to have a virtual function table (more memory, and a slightly slower function call).  This might be what you want, but these things are easier to introduce in C++ than in C.

Overall, C++ will let you introduce code that is larger and slower than C will.  But if you want those features then doing it in C is a pain (think of function pointers rather than a virtual function call ... they are effectively the same thing).  And the C version will end up taking the same time and resources, so there is no saving by using C.

Comment: Point #1 is an excellent point. With respect to #2 and #3, I don't think these are specific to the choice of language. For #2, that is a criticism of the dynamic array data structure, not the language n which it is implemented; C++ also has a not as popular std::list<> for linked lists (also custom allocators let you allocate in previously allocated memory). For #3, a good code review and style guide policy would be good to have regardless of language and would mitigate this.

Comment: I really was just looking to use C++ for encapsulation of certain operations. Namely, I2C and LCD interfacing that I already have written respective C libraries. I was just looking at how intuitive it would be to have an Lcd class rather than calling many independent functions that are related. Of course, it's really nearly the same thing, but Atmel Studio supports C++ and as such has the appropriate code-complete features that would make this very simple.

Comment: With vectors you can preallocate the array effectively controlling the amount of allocations that are performed. If you really want fully dynamically sized arrays `std::vector` is often a much more efficient solution to an home made version written in C, anyway.

Comment: @sherrellbc, as a trial run, you might want to maintain strictly C interfaces (extern "C" in C++) but provide the implementation in C++. This would allow you to test out C++ in the implementation of particular C APIs to sanity-check its usage in your project while limiting risk in case you need to re-implement that component in C after all.

Comment: @sherrellbc if you mean wrapping a C interface in C++ classes, I'd say it's not worth it. If the C++ wrapper let you abstract something away, then maybe. For example, if several LCDs are similar and you make a common interface to all of them. With a good compiler (see dave's point 1) a thin wrapper can be optimized away entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic dispatch (i.e. methods marked `virtual`) have slightly more cost (though negligibly so) than non-virtual methods (but, good news, you don't have to mark a method as `virtual` unless you intend to override it, and when you do use it, it will probably be faster than whatever you would have crafted by hand in C to do the same thing) and exception handling can be slow (though you don't need to use exceptions in your code). Other than that, there is no difference, except that C++ will greatly simplify  the code over the equivalent C code.

Comment: The point of writing C is not to write the equivalent to what you would write in C++ but to write something that would be highly non-idiomatic in C++ but vastly superior in size and performance. A canonical example would be having `prev`/`next` pointers directly in your structure and walking them with a trivial for loop rather than using a list container object.

Comment: @R, except to provide bindings to other languages, I have yet to see a compelling use case for choosing C over C++. Modern compiler optimizations make C++ just as performant, while the language -- if used well -- is vastly more readable than C.